# Test::WWW::Selenium::More with Moose

Tags: perl, moose

I'm attempting to use 'Test::WWW::Selenium::More' and 'Moose' while creating my own class called 'MySelenium' in Perl.

This is the Moose error when I run the program:

```
You must pass an even number of attribute options at /Library/Perl/5.18   /darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Exporter.pm line 422
Moose::has('host', 'localhost') called at MySelenium.pm line 5
require MySelenium.pm at x.pl line 5
main::BEGIN at MySelenium.pm line 0
eval {...} at MySelenium.pm line 0
Compilation failed in require at ./x.pl line 5, <DATA> line 438.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./x.pl line 5, <DATA> line 438.
```

Here is the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use MySelenium;
use Test::Most;

my $x = MySelenium->new;

$x->open_ok('/');

done_testing;
```

Here is my class called 'MySelenium'

```
package MySelenium;
use Moose;
extends 'Test::WWW::Selenium::More';

has host        => 'localhost';
has port        => 4444;
has browser     => 'firefox';
has browser_url => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str',
default => 'http://www.google.com');

    sub login_ok {
    my ($self, $username, $password) = @_;
    $self->open_ok('/login');
    $self->is_text_present_ok('Please login thanks');
    $self->type_ok('username' => $username);
    $self->type_ok('password' => $password);
    $self->follow_link_ok('login');
}

no Moose;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting up your Moose attributes correctly.  Try following this pattern:

```
has host => (
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'Str',
    default => 'localhost',
);
```

I see you're already doing this for `browser_url`.  Just make sure you set up all of your attributes in this way.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [oalders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181828/1331451), if you want to add stuff to an existing object, you need to use the `has +foo` notation. It looks like `host` and `port` are already attributes and you just want to change their default value.

```
has '+host' => ( default => 'localhost' );
```

Also [see the Moose doc on `has` and `has +`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#has-name-options).